# MacVim copy selection from vim command line shell to MacVim or OS clipboard

Tags: vim, macvim

I run commands from MacVim itself using the `!` character to execute the command.

e.g. `!go test`

The command spews allot of text. I want to select a subset of the text, using my "mouse" and then paste only the selected line back into MacVim or even the MacOS clipboard.

I have searched for answers by nothing apparent seems to be working for me.

Copying from MacVim to the MacOS clipboard is working for me using the mouse selection and then `CMD+c` with `CMD+v`.

However when I use the above procedure from the "shell" output this does not work.

I have MacVim version 8.0.1633 (146) and the shell it is using is bash.

When I use `"vim"` from iTerm itself I am able to copy and paste without
problems, the shell I am using then is zsh. Using `"Terminal"` and bash also works.

Comment: I found the mistake, when the command line has many text a `---More----` message is displayed. After a couple of key presses one sees a message `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, only once this message is displayed does copy and paste work as it should.

Comment: Please write your solution as an actual answer and then mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: Copy and paste works when the end of the output is reached.

When the vim "shell" command generates many lines of text as output, a message is displayed that reads: `---More----`

After a couple of key presses one sees a message `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, only once this message is displayed does copy and paste work as it should.